# white screen after logoff in cordova android app

Tags: android

I am getting white screen after trying to change the page after logoff from the app.

```
        var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage").attr("id");
        if (activePage != "splashScreenPage") {
            console.log("in Active page >>> ");
            $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "../../index.html", 
                            {reload : false, showLoadMsg : true });
        }
```

This is what I am doing, has anyone faced the similar issue. I have tried searching on stackoverflow about white screen in cordova, but none of those solutions have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by removing `android:launchMode="SingleTop"` from android manifest file. More about launchMode can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode)